# Draggable carousel menu with different item size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a horizontal menu with different item widths which I want to act like a draggable carousel menu (you do this kind of dragging in iPhone and Android screens everyday). 
I found many jQuery Addon like [OWL Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) which do this. However all this addons require a fixed width for all items and to specify how many items I want to show per viewport.

considering a menu like `Home, Administration, Stock, Reports, Personalization`, items are not same width. I don't know the screen width either so I cannot decide how many items per viewport I can show either.This is required for most of carousel scrolls.

Consider following diagram. The outer box is the container div. Items marked with 1~6 are menu items which are simple links (a tags). Items 1~3 are visible (4 is partially visible) and items 5 and 6 are hidden.

```
+---------------------------+
| +----+ +---------+ +---+ +----+ +------+ +---------+
| | 11 | | 2222222 | | 3 | | 44 | | 5555 | | 6666666 |
| +----+ +---------+ +---+ +----+ +------+ +---------+
+---------------------------+
```

Dragging over container will move all items to left or right. after drag stopped, closest menu item should snap to left border of container (with animation). left border of items is point of measure with ignoring negative sign. Also if all items fit in container no drag is possible and last item only snaps to right border of the menu not allowing more drag. Clicking an item without drag should navigate.
It is not important if last item in viewport is partially visible.

**Problem**

I made the menu and I can drag it to left and right. I have trouble with the snapping closest item to left border of container. I can do this in Javascript and jQuery but my solution become so complex that I am lost in it myself.

**Question**

Is there any existing jQuery addon which can do this?
If not, how can I create the animation to snap items?

Answer (score -1):

OWL Carousel - autoWidth:true

or

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php - Partial Slides Display

Comment: don't post just the links. Consider quoting the desired text from there to your answer